# When I extend an interface A with interface B, will A's methods be available for free to B's implementors?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I'm curious how this all works. I have an interface, let's call it `A`. When I look at `A`, it has most of the methods I need, but not all, and I don't have control over interface `A`, so I extend it with interface `B` which implements the 1 or whatever number of methods that I need on top of `A`.

```java
public interface B extends A {

    String doSomethingFun(String blah);

}
```

`A` has an implementation class called `Client`. In just a second I'm going to create my own implementation class of `B` called `MyDefaultClient`.

I then create a concrete class that implements `B`, like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyDefaultClient implements B {

    private A myClient;

    @Autowired
    public MyDefaultClient(A myClient) {
        this.myClient = myClient;
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomethingFun(String filename) {
        // custom business logic
    }

    @Override
    public String serviceName() {
        return myClient.serviceName();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        myClient.close();
    }

}
```

`serviceName()` and `close()` are methods that A forces its implementors to implement. There are other methods though that have default implementations that aren't forcing me to implement them, I assume simply because they have default implementations.

At this point I have a concrete class that I can instantiate in other places and call all of both `A` and `B`'s methods on it. But is that only because in the interface there are default implementations for these methods, like this?

```java
default Blah someMethodInA(String thing) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

If I use this code and call `myDefaultClient.doSomethingFun("hello")` I'm pretty certain that will do the thing I want it to do. But what about if I call `myDefaultClient.someMethodInA()`? Will it call the implemented method in `Client`, which is `A`'s implementor? Or will it fall on the floor and complain with an `UnsupportedOperationException`? If the latter, is there any way I can structure this so that I can call all of `A`'s methods from `B`'s implementor?

Comment: is A an interface or an abstract class? interfaces cannot have implementations. EDIT: They added default methods to interfaces in java 8 and I didnt even notice. seems confusing.

Comment: Why does `MyDefaultClient` both implement `B` and contain an instance of `B`? And no, there are no default implementations for default methods. When you extend an interface, it's the same as if you copy pasted the contents of the superinterface to the subinterface. And if you're wondering, try it and see, instead of asking whether you get an error.

Comment: Ah my bad, good catch Kayaman. Fixed it so that `MyDefaultClient` has an instance of `A`, not `B`.

Comment: Why on Earth should a method call on `MyDefaultClient` end up at the entirely unrelated class `Client`? Of course, it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `MyDefaultClient` to *inherit* implementations from `Client`, then it has to extend `Client`, like this:

```
class MyDefaultClient extends Client implements B
{
    ...
}
```

Then, if `Client implements A`, you will only have to provide implementations for the new methods that `B` adds.

or... you *can* continue your current pattern and explicitly delegate all the calls you want to a field of type `A`, but you will have to do them all explicitly, even the methods with default implementations.  The default implementations will continue the throw exceptions if you don't override them.

Answer (score 1):

An interface can have any number of `default` methods. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) for more details. Given below is an example to demonstrate how `default` methods and extending an `interface` work:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    public void toBeImplementedA();

    default void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    default void hi() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}


public interface InterfaceB extends InterfaceA {
    public void toBeImplementedB();
}


public class AnImplClass implements InterfaceB {

    @Override
    public void toBeImplementedA() {
        System.out.println("toBeImplementedA");
    }

    @Override
    public void toBeImplementedB() {
        System.out.println("toBeImplementedB");
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InterfaceB obj = new AnImplClass();
        obj.toBeImplementedA();
        obj.toBeImplementedB();
        obj.hello();
        obj.hi();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
toBeImplementedA
toBeImplementedB
Hello
Hi
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can contain default methods. These were added to Java so that an interface could be updated without forcing implementing code to be rewritten.¹

Default methods provide an implementation if your implementing class does not implement them.

When you call methods on an object, the overridden method is always called.

Any other implementations in the super classes / interfaces are used when there is a lack of implementation.

Even if you refer to MyDefaultClient as A,

```
A myImplementation = new MyDefaultClient();
```

Under the hood `myImplementation` is still an instance of `MyDefaultClient` even though the code views it as `A`. Therefore your overriden method will be used when `doSomethingFun` is called.

```
    @Override
    public String doSomethingFun(String filename) {
        // custom business logic
    }
```

¹ Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: That link is broken, just so you know.

Comment: There was a bracket at the end of it by mistake.